# I have this executable (application/x-executable) but it is not executing when I click on it

Tags: software-installation, files, bitcoin

I have the Execoin Wallet executable file. I have tried opening it with lots of programs but nothing seems to happen.

I am a newbie to Linux, don't know how to do much. If you do answer, can it be fully explained?

I just need to know how to execute the file as it doesn't seem to work.
sorry I did what you said about making it an executable before i opened the forum.
i am sorry i didnt give enough information:
the file is a executable (application/x-executable)(copied from the properties section of the file)
I am wondering if there is a setting wrong in my system and not the file?
sorry that i didnt reply sooner.
thank you in advance

Comment: Please provide a screenshot.

Comment: @Raphael I don't think that is necessary here, what would a screenshot show? Could you expand on what it should be of?

Comment: It might be a command-line application. In that case, you may need to use Terminal to open it.

Comment: Does the file have a `.exe` extension? What is the full file name?

Comment: Are you using the `.jar` file from the Execoin website? Have you looked at the [README](https://github.com/pavel4n/exelite.org/blob/master/README) (from the source)? This has links which should help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to open it in nautilus (the file manager)

Right click on it, and go to the permissions tab. Then tick the box `Allow executing this file as a program`.

Now you should be able to double click and it runs.

From terminal:

`chmod +x /path/to/your/filename.extension`

Comment: does the answer work for you

Comment: If you're more comfortable with command line (or prefer it) you can also do `chmod +x /path/to/your/filename.extension`

Comment: @musher Thanks, couldn't find the command I was looking for! It doesn't seem to be on Ask Ubuntu anywhere...